# Kafka SMT for datetime conversion in ISO UTC datetime format

Tags: datetime, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to convert a column of type `datetime` in MySQL be converted to UTC-ISO DateTime format in the source connector?

Input Details
Column Name: Modified_dtmStamp
Sample Value: 2018-08-03 16:37:20

```
... 
"transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "Modified_dtmStamp",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.format": "ISO_INSTANT",
        "transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp"
```

Implemented the above snippet referring to https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html.

Error:

```
"trace": "org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'I' for configuration TimestampConverter requires a SimpleDateFormat-compatible pattern for string timestamps: ISO_INSTANT\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter.configure(TimestampConverter.java:263)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig.transformations(ConnectorConfig.java:257)\n\tat ........
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Changing the `format` to `yyyy-MM-dd` in the above connector snippet works as given in the examples.

However, looking for UTC-ISO format specifically. ISO_INSTANT does the trick, but not working in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`ISO_INSTANT` isn't a SimpleDateFormat string format, it's a static field within `java.time.*` API, which Connect doesn't use

You'd have to explicitly write out the full value for "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Given that, how do I convert it to UTC?

Comment: It is not clear what format you want. Every option for `target.type` is in UTC... I do not think there is any target type that matches ISO-8601 like `2019-05-01T17:24:47Z`, but I personally don't think that should matter. You should prefer to parse a string into a milliseconds since epoch, then any consumer should be able to reformat that at consumption time.